# Run shared library code at end of Jenkins pipelines without modification to Jenkinsfiles

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Is there a way via a loaded shared library to automatically run a snippet of code at the end of the job even if the method wasn't called?

sort of an event model where we'd have OnJobEnd like hook to tie code to.  This would mean I could add the finishing without touching 100s of Jenkinsfiles.

I think the answer is no, but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like the [Global Post Script Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/global-post-script/).